# Convert formulas to arrayformulas problem

Tags: google-sheets, search, filter, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas

How can the formula

```
=iferror(vlookup(filter(Keywords!$A:$E,search(Keywords!$A:$A,M2),Keywords!$E:$E=$B$2:$B),Keywords!$A:$T,20,0),"<No Keyword>"))
```

be converted into an arrayformula, so it does not need to be placed in every single cell?

```
={"mCategory";
arrayformula(if(isblank($M$2:$M),,
iferror(vlookup(filter(Keywords!$A:$E,search(Keywords!$A:$A,$M$2:$M),Keywords!$E:$E=$B$2:$B),Keywords!$A:$T,20,0),"<No Keyword>"))
)}
```

doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Google Sheets question or Excel?

Comment: An example sheet shared for edit would help also.